# Open Wordpress in ampps localhost from Nox emulator

Tags: android, wordpress, localhost, emulation, ampps

In the Android Nox emulator using 192.168.56.1 in a browser I can see the files and folders in the main directory of my localhost ampps, but when clicking on a folder where I have Wordpress installed, it indicates that this website cannot be accessed, is it necessary to configure something additional in Nox?

Comment: did you install wordpress directly in the `/` of the ampps or sub folder ? for example `http/192.168.56.1/index.php` will work from your computer browser ?

Comment: Hello Dickens, navigating from Chrome in the Nox emulator using 192.168.56.1 if the wordpress is installed in the main directory, it only shows the home, it does not load styles or images, nor can I navigate through the internal links of that wordpress, the external links if do they work. Everything works as it should from a desktop browser. My idea is and I suppose that this is how many use it, to test what the wordpress looks like on mobile screens and android tablets using the Nox emulator.

Comment: please translate this in English

Comment: from your comment, I understood that you have difficulty in WordPress installation with .htaccess and Apache Rewrite , I advice you to fix that first, Nox has nothing to do with this

Comment: It seems to be what you indicate, but using a browser from the desktop everything works well, so it seems to me that I need to configure something in Nox